# Access violation when creating ActiveX control after upgrading to C++Builder 11

Tags: activex, c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

The following code creates an ActiveX component on a hidden form. It works well with C++Builder 10.4, but crashes when compiled with C++Builder 11.0.

```
container = new TForm((TComponent*)NULL);
container->Visible = false;
softlock = new TCryptoLicense(container); // <= A.V.
softlock->Parent = container;
```

The Access Violation occurs in the constructor of `TControl` after `CreateTouchManager`, when it uses `FTouchManager`. I have already tried the following things that did not help:

- make the form visible
- add an Owner to the Form constructor
- call `HandleNeeded` on the container
- create it delayed, not in startup of application

Dropping the component unto a form in a new application caused the same exception to occur at design time.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it by single stepping into the TCryptoLicense constructor ?

Comment: @RogerCigol yes, and then when you get to the TControl constructor it crashes at the mentioned point.

Comment: So perhaps you haven't posted a particularly useful code snippet. It would be more useful to have the constructor for TCryptoLicense - since that's where the problem is....

Comment: The exception is in the constructor of TControl (of which the activex component inherits) which is standard VCL code.

Comment: But what causes the exception may well not be in that "standard" code. If TControl constructor were to fail very little would be working..... You need to post the code snip that leads up to this problem.... Also state which compiler you are using....

Answer (score 0):

Reimporting the ActiveX control into a new package fixed the problem. Maybe some data from CB10 and CB11 got mixed up.